# Skew/Shear of image by different degrees

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I was wondering if anyone could check my code on skew/shear of images. It skews the image, but not efficiently. It seems like something is not working properly.it just gives me a white skewed image

```
clear all
img1 = imread('image.jpg');imshow(img1);
[m,n,p]=size(img1);


NumPixels = n*m;
[Points(1,:) Points(2,:)] = ind2sub([n m],1:NumPixels);

thetas = 30;
sx = 1/tand(thetas);

Sx = [1 sx; 0 1];

Points_tform = round(Sx * Points);

n_t = max(Points_tform(1,:));
m_t = max(Points_tform(2,:));

img_t = zeros(n_t,m_t);

for k = 1:length(Points)
   try img_t(Points_tform(2,k),Points_tform(1,k)) = img1(Points(2,k),Points(1,k),1); 
   catch
       a=1;
   end
end


figure;
imshow(img_t);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Matlab already has [tools](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/images/ref/imtransform.html) for shearing images. Have you tried them?

Comment: I know, but I'm not supposed to use any built in functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a [shear matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_matrix) to speed up your shearing alot

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with my code above that it's giving me white skewed image instead of whatever image I read.

Comment: Sorry, I currently don´t have Matlab at hand to test your code and i have never done shearing without using a Matrix. Maybe if you comment all important steps in your code we can provide better help.